# How to show web site content on Android rss app

Tags: android, listview, webview, web, rss

I am developping an `Android` news application. I want to show rss website content when i click on list object on screen. I am using `jsoup` library with rss link on `webview`. But this way does not make me feel normal. Because it has some performance issue i think.

What is the best way for this approach ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Well, to get data from RSS the best way will be using XmlPullParser.
You can see a great example [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_rss_reader.htm).

Comment: you could not understand the situation i think. Because i can get and parse all rss feed with saxparser. My question is about getting website content.

Comment: As far as I know, if the website is not letting you to receive this content you can't pull it.
Even if you will try to set elements, it's not something that I know is possible.

Comment: Yes, but what is the normal way when i pull the content. What should the design be ?